# Not able to get localStorage value

Tags: javascript, web, local-storage

my function is

```
var map = function(doc) {
if(doc.type=='task'){
   if ( doc.admin == localStorage.Mobile_No )
      emit(doc.task_creation_time, doc);
   }
}
```

console.log(map) should return like

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.type=='task'){
   if ( doc.admin == "1234567890" )
      emit(doc.task_creation_time, doc);
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is this function meant to do, and what is the typical value of `doc`? From this alone, it's hard to understand what exactly's the issue.

Comment: What part of the code doesn't work? Are you sure the values of `doc` are what you think they are? Are you sure the value of `localStorage.Mobile_No` is what you think it is?

Comment: How are you telling you are not able to get the value localStorage. 
Try to check the value in webinspector tools of chrome or safari. You may get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you did something like this:

```
var map = new Function("doc", 
    "if(doc.type=='task'){" + "\n"
    "   if ( doc.admin == \"" + localStorage.Mobile_No + "\")" + "\n"
    "      emit(doc.task_creation_time, doc);" + "\n"
    "   }" + "\n"
    "}");
```

you could achieve what you seem to be looking for.  But for heaven's sake, *why*?

---

The JS engine is not going to magically rewrite your source-code just because it found a value in localStorage.  What would happen if you changed that value?  Should the function suddenly updated itself?

Comment: Why not achieve this with closure rather than effectively an `eval`?

Comment: Oh, I would.  But then `console.log(map)` would not return the way the OP seems to want.  I see no reason in the world for doing this, and I think the OP is barking up something that's probably not even made of wood, but this seems to meet the requirements.

Comment: `var map = (function (num) {return function (doc) {if (doc.type === 'task' && doc.admin === num) emit(doc.task_creation_time, doc);};}(localStorage.Mobile_No));`, but yes, the `console.log` would look different.

Comment: Yes, it's straightforward to write one that has the correct functionality, but how will it appear in the console, which is what the question asked about?